# Should a method called by a constructor be static?

Tags: java, static

I am making a simple bible reader for a confirmation project, and I have a UI class. The class opens a windows when called by the main class. I just satisfied multiple errors with static keywords, but one thing is left - my prepareGUI method. Should it be declared static? My IDE throws no errors either way.

```
package input;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class UI extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4226151097999382106L;

    private static JFrame mainFrame;
    private static JLabel headerLabel;
    private static JLabel statusLabel;
    private static JPanel controlPanel;

    public UI() {
        prepareGUI();
    }

    private static/* Should that be there? */ void prepareGUI() {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Holy Bible");
        mainFrame.setSize(700, 500);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        headerLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        statusLabel = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);

        statusLabel.setSize(350, 100);

        controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
        mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
        mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
        headerLabel.setText((String) ReadFile.currentBookData[0]);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setText((String) ReadFile.currentBookData[2]);
        label.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 12));
        controlPanel.add(label);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void updateText() {
        headerLabel.setText((String) ReadFile.currentBookData[4]);
        statusLabel.setText((String) ReadFile.currentBookData[4]);
    }

}
```

Comment: I personally believe the fields should not be `static` and randomly adding keywords to your code is not a successful long-term programming strategy.

Comment: The compiler will only show errors for code that is actually invalid, per the language rules - such as wrong syntax or mismatched types. It won't guard against poor design choices or most logical errors. (I suggest reading up on what `static` *actually* does before deciding to use it.)

Comment: @Elliott those are not random, they were leftovers from a snippet I was referencing.

Comment: @CaffeineToCode Randomly adding `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you "fixed" your error goes against the concept of OOP. `static` methods and fields are meant to be "properties" of the class itself, where non-static methods and fields are "properties" of an instance (object) of said class.

What you should do is remove the `static` keyword from your fields and your `prepareGUI()` method:

```
//private JFrame mainFrame; you only have one instance, so no point in having a global field
private JLabel headerLabel;
private JLabel statusLabel;
private JPanel controlPanel;

private /*static Should that be there? answer is no. */ void prepareGUI() {
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Holy Bible");
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `UI` class have all `static` fields, that's why you need to mark `prepareGUI()` method as `static`. Beware! each time you create object of `UI` class, you just overwrite existing `mainFrame`.

If you are creating only single instance of your `UI` class, then it is better to use `Singleton` pattern to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You're fixing things the wrong way. The solution is not to make everything static, but to solve your initial code problem so that the statics aren't needed to begin with. Please understand that the reason object-oriented programming was developed was to give code structure that reduced code complexity and increased code re-use. By making all this static, you throw all that benefit to the wayside.

Answer (score 1):

For swing code like this, making the members static does not seem like a good choice. these members are things that are associated with one instance of the class, not with the class as a whole. It is reasonable to initialize the components in the constructor, even if they are instance members.

The examples in the Oracle tutorial are hard to get to, and the tutorial insists on you using NetBeans. But the [examples for the O'Reilly Swing book](http://examples.oreilly.com/jswing2/code/) are easy to find and they initialize the components in the constructor. That would be a better example to follow than using static fields.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor method should only initialize the class members, and that's it. The best practice would be to call the static method afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

static is necessary when you want call that method or attribute directly..i mean without create an object from class
static methods or attributes can called in other classes without creating Object like this -> Classname.staticMethod();